# Error installing ubuntu-desktop on 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install ubuntu-desktop on 14.04 but when I run `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` it gives error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
```

With synaptic, it shows red mark on this package. I tried with `apt-get clean` as well as `apt-get update` but no success.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-mark showhold` and then posting the output here.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness  showhold command does not output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you can not install the *ubuntu-session* packge.  That package conflicts with the *gnome-session* and *ubuntu-settings* packages.  To find out more, I would try `apt-get install ubuntu-session` and see what errors it gives.